# How to Customize AlertDialog and use Future <List>

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a project with flutter and firestore. It is a Home Automation project. In this project, I have lots of cards that can turn stuff ON and OFF, currently, for each user, I have created 3 main cards, that are created when they sign up.
 What I'm trying to do right now is, with an ADD button, I will create another card with the info that the user wants to set to that card. I could manage to create the info in my firestore but, The user can't select what goes on it. That's what I'm trying to fix right now. So, when the user clicks the ADD button, **I'm creating an AlertDialog that he can put his info to create the new button**. What I tried to do was create an AlertDialog, but I don't know why when I attempt to set more TextFields to it (I will need 4) it won't work. And with this AlertDialog I created a Future that was suppose to return a List, but only seems to work with String.
This is the code for the Dialog:

```
Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context){

  TextEditingController customController = TextEditingController();

  return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Text'),
      content: TextField(
        controller: customController,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        MaterialButton(
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Text("OK"),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString());
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

When the user types his info that's how I gathered what he typed:

```
createAlertDialog(context).then((value){
                                    print(value);
                                  });
```

Later on I will insert this list data to the firestore, this is an example:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid)
                                  .collection('buttons').document('button'+ cardamount.toString()).setData({
                                    'activelabel': ListFromAlert[0],
                                    'icondata': ListFromAlert[1],
                                    'inactivelabel': ListFromAlert[2],
                                    'text': ListFromAlert[3]                                        
                                  });
```

If there is a way to create an Alert Dialog that I could customize so I can set more TextFields and position Stuff differently, please suggest. Thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have a `Column` in the `content` of your `AlertDialog`, containing multiple `TextField`s with their own `TextEditingController`.

```
content: Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: customController1,
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: customController2,
    ),
  ],
),
```

`content` takes any type of `Widget`. This can be a nested structure with multiple columns, rows, etc. and can have padding or specific height or widths.

After that, just create a list of the values when you call `pop`

```
onPressed: (){
  final values = [
    customController1.text.toString(),
    customController2.text.toString(),
  ];
  Navigator.of(context).pop(values);
},
```

About this issue `'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3580 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.`

You might be referencing the wrong `context` in the Navigator. Try renaming `context` to `ctx` for the builder's argument:

`showDialog(context: context, builder: (ctx){`

and use that for the Navigator:

`Navigator.of(ctx).pop(values);`

Comment: Oh that's a great, but lets suppose I wan't to possition one text in the top right and one in the bottom left, Could I just add paddings, and rows, etc?

Comment: And if I wanted to expand the widht and height of the alert, could I do that too?

Comment: I'm getting this error too: ``` 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3580 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I could determine a Container and set height and widht in the content right?

Comment: Yes, you can use Container, SizedBox, or any other widget

Comment: Great, Thank you mate!